# What research was being performed on Pinky and the Brain?

Tags: pinky-and-the-brain, animaniacs

Pinky and the Brain are mice in a scientific laboratory of some sort.

What, if any experiments are being performed on them?

Comment: They took the brain from pinky and put it in the brain.

Comment: Same thing we research every night, Pinky. How to take ...

Comment: +1 just for asking about Pinky and the Brain

Comment: Their twilight campaign is easy to explain...

Answer (score 47):

Some form of genetic experimentation, involving gene splicing, but I'm not aware of anything more specific than that.

> They're Pinky and The Brain
>   Yes, Pinky and The Brain
>   One is a genius
>   The other's insane
>   They're laboratory mice
>   **Their genes have been spliced**

Comment: Presumably, it was this splicing that increased the Brain's intelligence. Pinky would likely then be the result of a failed experiment, or maybe a control subject.

Comment: @Roger not necessarily. there's a fan theory out there that says it's actually the reverse: Pinky is the smart one that knows how to do stuff and the Brain is a failed experiment with delusions of grandeur. There's an episode where Pinky writes a formula, Brain corrects it, but it's his version that fails instead of Pinky's. there's also a minor implication due to the order of their names and assigned qualities in the intro.

Comment: @NateKerkhofs Don't forget that One is a Genius, and the other is insance. Brain is clearly the insane one - he consistently tries to take over the world. Pinky keeps stopping him - the genius.

Comment: That's what I meant with the minor implication.

Comment: I've read that theory, yes, and it's definitely an interesting (and not improbable) idea. But regardless, Brain's intelligence has clearly been enhanced, even if it happened to cause the side effect of delusional behavior.

Comment: I would just like to thank you fellows in the comments for warping my understanding of a childhood program for the rest of my life :)

Comment: I will take some google-fu to find it, but I recall another site walking thru the logic of Pinky's statements.. Basically, he seems to go into non-sequiturs, but he's just not 'showing his work' -- if you follow the chain of logic behind it, his statements make sense.

Comment: @NateKerkhofs - Mind. Blown.

Comment: I wouldn't say it's just a fan theory - Season 3 pretty much said as much. See the S3 episodes "Pinky's Plan", "Pinky's Turn" and "The Pinky P.O.V" for evidence.

Comment: @NateKerkhofs [Billie](http://pinkyandthebrain.wikia.com/wiki/Billie) is possible further in-series evidence of that theory; she resembles Pinky far more than Brain, and is also smarter than Brain

Comment: Isn't there a specific episode, the one that introduced Snowball, that explicitly shows how they became more than ordinary lab mice?

Comment: Yeah, the gene splicing thing is likely correct. That, or they're working on the same things the science department of NERV from Neon Genesis Evangelion is working on: in one episode you can see a symbol that looks like the face of Lilith and the symbol of SEELE as used in Rebuild (the triangle with three eyes on one side and four on the other). But if this is the case, then NGE has this as a shoutout to PatB, given that the latter came first.

Comment: One of the producers said in an interview that Pinky is the genius. If I could just find it, I'd show you. I'd show you all.

Comment: @KHW: Is this *Cracked* article the one you were talking about? http://www.cracked.com/article_20382_5-fan-theories-about-cartoons-that-will-ruin-your-childhood_p2.html

Comment: @JamesSheridan -- Nope; the article I read actually walked thru a bunch of his statements and explained why they made sense. It was.. bizarre.  I'd actually guess it was a Usenet posting, from way back when./